# Are there any other ways besides motion tracking?

Tags: tracking, compositing-nodes

I have an animated model with vertex parented empties (img 1)
I need to transfer these positions to another blend file so that they are on the same z coordinate. And so that there was a camera on top. (img 2)
This is for compositing.
How do I transfer dummy positions? I know 1 way - tracking. But it’s crazy to track your own video. There must be another way.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you copy the object and paste it onto a new Blender file, it will be at the exact same position as the first file.  If I misunderstood the question, be sure and tell me.

Comment: You might have to copy the empties as well, if it's parented to the empties.

Comment: @RBlong2us In file 2, the emptis should move relative to the camera (
just like they move in file1, when the camera is on the side or can fly around.), but in file 2 they must be on the same z position and camera fixed

Comment: ok, I'm gonna explain what you want, and tell me if I'm right.  You have the camera moving in file one, and the empties are fixed.  In the new file, you have the camera fixed and you want the empties to move, while staying in the same z coordinate

Comment: @RBlong2us yes. but in file 1 emptys attached to mesh, which animated. so in file 1 camera moving + emptys moving. in file 2 camera fixed

Comment: wow, I'm not sure how to do that.  Why do you need this?

Comment: might be another angle

Comment: @RBlong2us I want to attach text to empties positions. i cant do it on file 1 because too much camera moving and too much objects.
the text should be parallel to the camera and at the same distance from the camera
 so i need transfer emptis positions to file 2, attach text and then composite with video from file 1.

Comment: would copying the camera and empties onto a new blend file, while still using the same animation work?

Comment: or is there a difference?

Comment: oh, they won't stay parallel?

Comment: @RBlong2us i have no idea how to copy empties. because they attached to vertexes of animated model.

Comment: you could copy empties with the monkey, then just make it so the model doesn't render in the outliner.

Comment: If you'd like, you could upload the .blend file, and I could take a crack at it.